# Improving throughput to Dynamics CRM via asynchronous C# OData (Simple.Odata.Client)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dynamics-crm, odata, batch-processing

I've recently been assigned to a project, where all the batchjobs are being handled through horribly optimized SSIS packages, and I'm currently trying to create POC Console.Application which will handle the entire process instead.

The POC is already 400% faster than the SSIS packages, so the performance gain is already making the project worth it, however I am still not impressed by the throughput of the application, and I am seeking advice on how to possibly improve performance.

I'm doing all CRUD related operations, but I'll use Deletion as an example here. The Entities are POCO classes, with a [Table] and around 55 [Column] annotations, two of them are Lookup columns. So it is not an extremely convoluted class, although there is a bit of data, ofcourse.

With this setup, I reach around 27 records per second deletion, which I am not really impressed by.

Setup:
Threads: 4 (Mainly Letting Parallel.ForEach handling it on its own, but around same performance with MaximumDegreeOfParallelism at 4, and following the guidelines of )
Maximum batch size = 500 (No discernible difference from 100-500)

I ended up with the numbers for the setup based on the official documentation and a lot testing with the POC.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/administration/operational-limits-online

I'll use a Deletion method as an example, but they are all built around the same-ish logic.

```
var client = GetClient();
var entityList = GetEntitiesForDeletion();
var batchMaximumSize = 500;

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(entityList.Chunk(batchMaximumSize ), async (chunk, _) =>
{
   var batch = new ODataBatch(client);

   foreach (var entity in chunk)
   {
       batch += oDataClient => oDataClient.For<Entity>()
       .Key(entity.Id)
       .DeleteEntryAsync(_);
   }

   await batch.ExecuteAsync(_);
});
```

```
public static IODataClient GetClient()
    {
        const string baseAddress = "http://crm-address/";
        const string apiUrl = "api/data/v8.2";

        var crmDomain = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOMAIN");
        var crmUsername = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CRM_USERNAME");
        var crmPassword = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CRM_PASSWORD");

        var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(crmUsername, crmPassword, crmDomain)
        };

        var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress),
        };

        var odataSettings = new ODataClientSettings(httpClient, new Uri(apiUrl, UriKind.Relative));
        odataSettings.IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true;

        return new ODataClient(odataSettings);
    }
```

Could anyone tell me if I'm missing anything glaringly obvious?

I know there is a connection limit of 100 to the server, however, I do not know how to make use of all of those.
I also have the possibility to create several more service users for the project, if this could help.

Or is the Dynamics CRM OData WebApi just not that fast?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually connecting to dynamics business central, please ignore this.

Dynamics Crm generally means Dataverse / XRM in the power platform, the apps names vary between dynamics crm, dynamics 365 customer engagement, Dynamics sale / Service etc.

If you are using a dataverse, guidance will vary between online hosted versions and on premises.

A good place to start (for online) is the service protection limits https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/api-limits?tabs=sdk#how-to-maximize-throughput
This will help you understand what is going on in the server side.

In the maximize throughput section it will link you to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/send-parallel-requests?tabs=sdk

Which will help explain how to optimize operation throughput via the .net client or via the web api.